# Why is the bootstrap col-lg-6 not applied even at full screen?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The second div with 'some text' drops below the image when the browser is maximized even with this code.  Does something weird happen when you insert images into bootstrap columns?

```
<div class="row">        
    <div class="col-lg-6 " >                 
        <img src="images/goodtimes.jpg" alt=""/>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6  ">                 
        some text
    </div>              
 </div>
```

Comment: use `col-md-6` instead of `col-lg-6`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">        
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6" >                 
     <img src="images/goodtimes.jpg" alt=""/>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">                 
     some text
  </div>              
</div>

Use col-md-6 it will solve your problem
```

Comment: Can you expand upon why `col-md-6` fixes the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because `col-lg-6` only applies to large screens. It's not necessarily the browser full-screen. Applying `col-sm-6` as well ensures that the style is applied even at smaller screen sizes.

As mentioned by @hemnath mouli, other size applications will work as well. You screen is likely just too small to trigger this style.

Nothing "weird" should happen just from adding an `<img>` tag as you asked.

Comment: I was zoomed in on my screen because it's 720p.  Once I zoomed out, everything fit together correctly.  Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, that'll get you. That's one of the "perks" of responsive design, just not when you don't expect it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the row is inside of a **container** class.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">        
    <div class="col-lg-6" >                 
      <img src="images/goodtimes.jpg" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">      
      <p>Hello World</p>           
    </div>              
  </div>
</div>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro

If you're trying to preview it, the grid explanation will provide some insights on that. Make sure that the **col** class you assign to the element (i.e., **col-lg-6**) matches against the pixel width you're working with. For example, with the **col-lg-6**, the screen size must be at least **1170px** wide.